# Why do I get an error saying 'statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]'

Tags: c

I am confused why I get an error on these 5 lines. I'd assume it would be just a warning but my compiler is taking all warnings as errors.

```
  161 |     kernelBuffer->BaseAddress;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:162:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  162 |     kernelBuffer->BufferSize;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:163:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  163 |     kernelBuffer->Width;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:164:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  164 |     kernelBuffer->Height;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:165:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  165 |     kernelBuffer->PixelsPerScanLine;
```

This is the file where the errors are happening 'main_uefi.c' https://pastebin.com/B5iTTzP5

Any idea why this could be happening and what I need to do to understand why this happens?

Comment: The error message seems fairly self-explanatory.  Those statements don't have any net effect, so they could just be removed entirely.  What do you expect them to do?

Comment: How exactly are you compiling?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "has no effect" means "doesn't do anything". I'm not sure why this is unclear. (Is English your first language?) Perhaps you thought these lines of code should do something? If you did, then we can only help you understand if you *explain* that first. *What* did you think should happen when this code runs? *Why* should that happen?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it is supposed to be passed to my kernel which is a whole different project from this. I was confused why it would be an error and it could be simply a warning and when I include that folder it would have an effect and the warning is gone. Thank you, it just clicked in my brain.

Comment: Oh, pardon. "but my compiler is taking all warnings as errors." The reason for this is that the compiler has been explicitly told to do that. (Specifically, the `-Werror=unused-value` in the error message tells you the compiler option that made this happen.) I assumed you knew that already, since you're the one running the compiler. "and when I include that folder it would have an effect " I have no idea what this means - what folder are you referring to? How are you "including" it? Why would that change the code on those lines?

Comment: What the code *does* (in an obfuscated way) is to verify that the frame buffer actually contains these fields. Otherwise you would get a *different* error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not performing an operation in those lines. Instead of a field of a struct pointer such as `kernelBuffer->BaseAddress;`, imagine you had a primitive value, like `int x;`. Hopefully you can see why a line like `x;` does nothing. There's no assignment or any other operation: nothing for the program to actually do. If you removed those lines, none of the coded functionality would change one bit, which is what the warning is telling you.